# Create custom designed bar graph on web page

Tags: html, css, asp-classic, bar-chart

I need to cerate a web page with dynamic data shown in a designed bar graph. The design of the graph has first priority. Here's a link to an [image of the bar graph to create](http://i58.tinypic.com/2hp7or7.jpg).

What would be the best way to achieve this. I'm thinking of using a simple image of one bar and filling html table cells with that image. But probably there are better ways to do this.

I'm familiar with html css and asp.

Who want to give me a hint in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Try http://d3js.org/ but this question is likely to be closed as Off-Topic: Opinion or Off-Topic: Find me a library or tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some kind of javascript chart, you can find plenty of them over the net, I have experience with [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) and [ChartJS](http://www.chartjs.org/) , both of them are easy to use and are customizable with dynamic interface. You can use the graph with bars or with lines it really depends on you, you can use them both as well as this wont result in bad performance ! Here you can check a simple demo with them [High chart demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo) and [ChartJS docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/). Hope this helps.